# Bounding $L^p$ norms in terms of lower-order $L^q$ norms

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, real-analysis, measure-theory, inequalities

Suppose $f,g\in L^q(\Omega)$ ($\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$) for all $1\le q\le p$. Here, $L^p(\Omega)$ is defined with respect to some measure $\mu$ that is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure. Are there bounds on $\int|f-g|^p$ or $\int(f^p-g^p)$ in terms of $\int|f-g|^q$ for $q<p$?

**Update**. As pointed out in an answer below, without further assumptions this is false. At a high level, what I am trying to understand is the following: I wish to know the rate of convergence of $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$, but all I know is the rate of convergence in $L^q$ for some $q<p$. Can anything be said? It seems necessary to assume, at least, that $f_n,f\in L^r$ for some $r\ge p$.

For example, assuming sufficient regularity and additionally $L^2$ convergence of the gradients, [Ladyzhenskaya's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladyzhenskaya%27s_inequality) is precisely such a bound for the case $q=2$ and $p=4$.

Comment: The interpolation inequalities for a $p$-norm only work if you know the $q$-norm and the $r$-norm with $q\leq p \leq r$. I would guess that taking $h = f-g$ (it does not matter what $f$ and $g$ are) given by $h(x) = \big( \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{\ln^{[k]} x} ) \big)^{1/p}$ will get you a counterexample (here $\ln^{[k]}$ is an $k$-times iterated logartihm). The integrand of the $p$-norm is logarithmic [or an interation of such], while the integrand of q norms will be dominated by the power of $x^{-q/p}$. But given the amount of downvote, I suspect there is a textbook example.

Comment: PS: I think it's very unpolite that the downvoters and closers did not leave a comment...

Comment: For your updated question: if you know that $f_n, f$ are bounded in $L^r$ for $r > p$, then you can directly interpolate to get convergence in $L^p$. (You don't need to assume $f_n \to f$ in $L^r$.) Iosif's example shows that this is sharp: with just $r = p$ this is not enough.

Comment: @WillieWong It seems I don't know enough about interpolation, then! What kind of interpolation inequalities give such explicit bounds? (If there is a standard reference, please feel free to share it.)

Comment: If $q < p < r$ there exists $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that $1/p = (1-\theta)/q + \theta/r$. Then $$ \int |f|^p = \int |f|^{(1-\theta)p} |f|^{\theta p} \leq \left( \int |f|^q \right)^{(1-\theta)p/q} \left( \int|f|^r\right)^{\theta p / r} $$ by Holder. So if $f_n \to f$ in $L^q$ and $f_n, f$ are uniformly bounded (say by $M$) in $L^r$, you have that $$ \int |f_n - f|^p \leq \left( \int |f_n - f|^q \right)^{(1-\theta)p/q} \left( 2M \right)^{\theta p} $$ using triangle inequality.

Comment: Yes, it seems I had forgotten to try the simplest of interpolation bounds. If @IosifPinelis is willing, I would suggest adding this to his answer, and I will accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Such a bound is impossible in general. E.g., suppose that $\Omega=[0,1]$, $g=0$, and $f=a^{-1/p}1_{[0,a]}$, where $p>0$ and $a\downarrow0$. Then for any $q\in(0,p)$ we have $\int\lvert f-g\rvert^q=a^{1-q/p}\to0$, whereas 
$\int\lvert f-g\rvert^p=\int(f^p-g^p)=1\not\to0$.

Comment: This is a great counterexample. Do you have any idea if this extends to the case where either (a) $\int f^p-\int g^p \to 0$ or (b) $\int |f-g|^p \to 0$?

Comment: @JohnA : I am not sure how to understand your comment. Can you specify what kind of bound you want to prove or disprove?

Comment: My comment was vague so my apologies; please see my edits to the "example" in my post. I'm curious if there is any relationship between the rate of convergence in $L^q$ vs $L^p$. Again, I suspect, the answer is no, but I am not sure.

Comment: @JohnA : I am still not sure about what specifically you mean by "arbitrarily bad". Can you just state it in formal terms? Also, I see no point in saying $c\alpha_n\to0$, because you can always rescale $f_n$ and $f$ (by replacing them, say, by $f_n/(c\alpha_n)^{1/q}$ and $f/(c\alpha_n)^{1/q}$) to get $c\alpha_n$ replaced by $1$. Alternatively, you can similarly rescale $f_n$ and $f$ to get $\int|f-g|^p=\int|(f^p-g^p)=1$, as was done in my example.

Comment: It's probably better think of my question as asking "under what reasonable assumptions is such a bound possible". I edited my question to point out an example in Ladyzhenskaya's inequality, although this assumes a bit more than I wanted. (I am not sure about your point on $\alpha_n$, this is simply the rate of convergence.)

Comment: @JohnA: Ladyzhenskaya assumes **a lot more**. In effect it is assuming that your sequence of function converges in $L^p$ and $L^r$, and so necessarily converges in $L^q$ when $q\in (p,r)$. Additionally, in this setting if you have rates in $L^p$, then by interpolation you always get some rate in $L^q$, even without knowing anything about the rate of convergence in $L^r$.

Comment: @JohnA : Your question was fully answered. Your new question, concerning Ladyzhenskaya's inequalities (which also involve norms of the gradient), is a wholly different thing. If you now want to ask a general question as to when we have (say) $\|f\|_p=O(\|f\|_q)$ with $q\in(0,p)$, then this question is way too broad to be asked on MathOverflow.

Comment: Previous comment continued: In probability, cases of the inequality $\|f\|_p=O(\|f\|_q)$ with $q\in(0,p)$ are referred to as the hypercontractivity phenomenon -- see e.g. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176990550 and https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13708363-introduction-to-random-chaos

Comment: Previous comment continued: Yet another, rather different kind of studies where we have $\|f\|_p=O(\|f\|_q)$ with $q\in(0,p)$ is represented by so-called reverse  Hölder's inequalities; see e.g. inequality (3.6) in https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1993-340-01/S0002-9947-1993-1124164-0/S0002-9947-1993-1124164-0.pdf

Comment: The fault is mine. My original question did not mention the requirement that $\int|f-g|^p\to0$, and while your counterexample is nice, it misses the main intent of my question. As I suggest above, we can merge @WillieWong's comment with your answer and this would be satisfactory.